# How to use Master page in Electron Js Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, frontend, desktop-application

I am creating a ElectronJs Project.

Here i want to create a master page where i can store header navigation and footer.

I have created a `base.html` file. Now i want all code of `base.html` in every page.

In PHP we can do with

`include 'base.php';`

I want to do just like that in ElectronJs.

Comment: If we can do it with node.js it will also ok for me.

Comment: I have some suggestion to do with Node FS. How can i use that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the following JS web Frameworks and it will solve your problem
it provide the dynamic components

1. EJS EJS provide same as php include function
2. Angular Use angular selector to include headers,footers etc like below

   <app-header></app-header>
3. React JS
4. VUE JS

let me know if its not clear , comment in commenbox i will explain.

Comment: I want to write code in HTML. Which framework is suitable for me ??

Comment: using ejs try this
https://ejs.co/#install
find include keyword

Comment: i think EJS is easier for you , using react,angular, vue you need to read more docs,
EJS will be quick solution for you.

Comment: I didn't find the solution as expected but the framework can help me differently.